# Does equity premium puzzle affect option-implied RWDs using Arrow-Debreu equilibrium?

Tags: options, derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, density, real-world-measure

I am researching and learning about option-implied RNDs (risk neutral densities) and transformation to RWDs (risk world densities) using expected utility theory to compute risk aversion values.

This is quite a new field for me, however I am a bit aware (although not super extensively) of equity premium puzzle and ultra high risk aversion values that come from observed equity premium.

My transformation returns implied risk premium values as one of the parameters so I am not inputting any historical risk premia. However, are these in any way related? If yes/no, are you aware of any papers discussing this? Thank you.